# Creating a Numeric Pad without using the default Virtual Pad provided by Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I'd like to create a Number Pad myself for my application in order to put prices and I have two questions:

1)I don't know how to block the virtual pad of the EditText. Can anyone help me?
2)Using a TableRow with buttons is the best solution for making a Numeric pad?

Comment: You could just use a regular TextView if it's not going to be directly editable (as in, the user can't type into it normally with the keyboard). It seems like you'll be using the `setText()` method a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1 
you can use

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and in the manifest file of that Activity file use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` keyboard will never opens :)

for 2 YES

Answer (score 0):

you can change the input mode of the EditText object to Number and it will only show a Number Pad when touched. No reason to create your own

Comment: What this will give you depends entirely on the active IME.  The stock IME on some devices gives you a pad of numbers and little else, on others it gives you a full keyboard with the numbers row active and a full set of symbols below, which is not as clean if you only want digits.